# Monitor CPU utilization for each user

Tags: linux, cpu-usage

Is there any way to monitor the CPU utilization for each user at regular intervals

Currently using the `sar` command I am able to get the following output:

```
12:00:01 AM     CPU     %user     %nice   %system   %iowait    %steal     %idle
12:10:01 AM     all      4.72      0.00      1.56      0.49      0.00     93.23
12:20:01 AM     all      4.70      0.00      1.58      0.41      0.00     93.31
12:30:01 AM     all      1.89      0.00      0.93      0.12      0.00     97.06
```

What I need is a break down of the CPU used per user for the same time duration.

I can not install any new tools or commands.

Comment: Are you the administrator of the server?

Comment: @ewwhite yes, I am..

Comment: any particular distro?

Comment: @warren Suse Linux

Answer (score 0):

The `sar` utility does "*System* Accounting", what you need sounds more like "*Process* Accounting".

Since you "*cannot install any new tools or commands*", hopefully the `acct` [package](https://www.suse.com/LinuxPackages/packageRouter.jsp?product=server&version=11&service_pack=sp2&architecture=i386&package_name=acct) has already been installed.

Check for the following commands (and their `man` pages);

```
/usr/bin/ac
/usr/bin/sa
```

If you have a support contract, contact your vendor for details & support.
There are a [few online](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Process-Accounting/) [sources](http://linux.die.net/man/8/auditctl) as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `top` utility can show CPU utilization for each user.
[image]